# KDB+ query in QPython: Filter based on DataFrame list

Tags: python, kdb, qpython

I am using qpython to query into a KDB+ database and then performing operations on the output. `old_df` is output from an earlier qpython sync query which has `'[source_id]'` as a string column. Now am querying into another database `trades_database` which has the same fields (as `source_id`) under a different column name `customer` (also string, no issues in data type)

```
params = np.array([])
for i in old_df['source_id']:
    params = np.append(params, np.string_(i))

new_df = q.sync('{[w]select from trade_database where customer in w}', *params, pandas=True)
```

Unfortunately, there is very little available online to solve such queries. I have learned a fair bit from the questions asked in here, but am really stuck here. My list could be very long and so would need to write a query where it is taken as an input only.

I also tried:

```
new_df= q1.sync('{select from trades_database where customer in (`1234, `ABCD)}', pandas=True)
```

which works but I get 
`<qpython.qtype.QLambda object at 0x000000000413F710>`

How does one "unpack" a QLambda object?

Please ignore the 2nd question if I am not allowed to ask 2 questions in the same post pls. Apologies in that case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

here is what I did and it seems to work:

```
    params = np.array(one_id) #just input the initial id used to search for old_df, and not put the square brackets to make it into a list

    for i in old_df['source_id']:
        params = np.append(params,np.string_(i))
    params=np.unique(params)

    new_df = q1.sync('{[w]select from trades_database where customer in w}', params, pandas=True)
```